# Small written under inf

Tags: math-mode, formatting

I need to obtain something like this:
[image]

but everything I try put the written under inf on the same line or write them in an enormous font. What can I do?

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) as always here, please post a full minimal example so we can see what you are doing. (3) Assuming you are loading the `amsmath` package and that this is a displayed formula: `\inf_{\substack{u_1,u_2: \\ u_1+u_2=u}}`

Answer (score 3):

As daleif suggested, `\substack` is the tool.  However, the horizontal spacing can still be adjusted in various ways.  I show the raw result, and then with a `\mathclap` and some `\mkern`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,newtxmath}
\begin{document}
\[
F(x,z,u) = \inf_{\substack{u_1,u_2: \\ u_1+u_2=u}}
  \bigl\{F_1(x,z,u_1) + F_2(x,z,u_2)\bigr\}
\]\[
F(x,z,u) = \mkern6mu\inf_{\mathclap{\substack{u_1,u_2: \\ u_1+u_2=u}}}
  \mkern6mu\bigl\{F_1(x,z,u_1) + F_2(x,z,u_2)\bigr\}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

If controlling the vertical spacing of the stack is essential, here is a `tabstackengine` solution.  There is 4pt below the `\inf` and 2pt between the `\scriptstyle` items.  By increasing the vertical gap below `\inf`, the horizontal `\mkern` can also be reduced.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\stackMath
\TABstackMath
\TABstackMathstyle{\scriptstyle}
\begin{document}
\[
\renewcommand\useanchorwidth{T}
\setstackgap{S}{2pt}
F(x,z,u) = \mkern3mu\stackunder[4pt]{\inf}{\tabbedShortstack{u_1,u_2: \\ u_1+u_2=u}}
  \mkern3mu\bigl\{F_1(x,z,u_1) + F_2(x,z,u_2)\bigr\}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another way to obtain a netter hirizontal spacing without having to set math kernin manually is to use the `\smashoperator` command:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,newtxmath}

\begin{document}

\[
F(x,z,u) = \inf_{\substack{u_1,u_2: \\ u_1+u_2=u}}
  \bigl\{F_1(x,z,u_1) + F_2(x,z,u_2)\bigr\}
\]
\[
F(x,z,u) = \smashoperator{\inf_{\substack{u_1,u_2:\enspace \\ u_1+u_2=u}}}
\bigl\{F_1(x,z,u_1) + F_2(x,z,u_2)\bigr\}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]